# Set the background with the ctypes in the python but

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, background, ctypes

i want to change the background with the (ctypes) in the python and i use this code :

```
import ctypes


a = input(">>>>")
if a == 'image':
    address = input("Insert your image >>>>")
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, address, 10)
    print(':)')

else:
    print('!!!!!!!')
```

but when i insert the address of the image the background become black (

the address is correct because i use this code and it works :

```
address  = "C:\\Users\\IIIIIIII  A  IIIIIII\\Desktop\\IMG_20180224_081321_180.jpg"

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20,0,address ,10)
```

)

What should I do to be able to change the background with the first code.

Comment: Try setting the last parameter to `3` instead of `10`

Comment: No , it didn't work .